# Azure Search - Convert use part of phrase to apply boolean filter

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm starting to look into Azure Search and looking to use part of a search query to apply a filter to the results, but don't know if it's possible.

Search query:
 `2 story house with pool`

I would like to use:

- 2 story -> story ge 2
- with pools -> pool == 1

In my index, pool is a booleand field and story are numeric one, and then cannot be marked as searchable.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you could do this transformation with Azure Cognitive Search, but my personal preference would be to use a NLP tool to build your search query. The power of Cognitive Search is to have a fast and enriched index, but other tooling is better to transform human language to a search query.

Have you had a look at [luis.ai](https://luis.ai)? You could use this service for intent and entity extraction, in order to build the search query to feed to Cognitive Search.

Using a NLP tool like LUIS allows you to have a more natural input. If you just map `pools` to `pool == 1`, how will you handle input like 'without pools' or 'including a pool'. There are just too many different inputs (positive + negative) to handle, which is why you need an NLP tool that can do intent and entity extraction.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I'm looking for. Will take a look at it.